# Relation between numbers of stable and unstable fixed points or manifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

In 1D dynamical systems, it is well-known that in general between any two stable fixed points there is an unstable fixed point. How does this result generalize to higher dimensions? Are there general theorems that establish a connection between the number of stable fixed points versus unstable fixed points?

Of course in higher dimension the extra complication is that we could have higher dimensional manifolds defined by $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$, e.g. lines or surfaces. Are there general results for their stability in relation to the number of stable and unstable lines / surfaces / higher dimensional manifolds?

How about systems defined not on $\mathbb{R}^n$ but on some manifold?

Comment: I've personally never seen stable points topic in relation to diff geometry so disregard if this isn't useful. But what about a ball on a plateau  in 2 dimension with a gravitational force field. Clearly it has stable points at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "sometimes yes". The full statement is: for some particular classes of dynamical systems there is an analogue of [Morse inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_inequalities); see, for example, [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183523416) and [this](https://www.icmat.es/miembros/aenciso/resources/16.pdf). For gradient systems (as far as I understand) this is just a reformulation of Morse theory for critical points.

Comment: Glad that you pointed this out. Indeed, as you say. Morse-Smale and gradient system have a quite related structure. Some people would say that the Conley index also qualifies... but I will forget that. The reason why I didn't mention more than "no" is that I understand the question as whether we can deduce the existence of some other equilibria from the existence of some initial ones.

Comment: @JohnB Oh, I've decided that the title of question is more suitable for non-negative answer, so I mostly answered to the title :)

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have guessed correctly, the answer in no. Really the $1$-dimensional is topological: in particular you need not have stable/unstable **hyperbolic** fixed points, only the directions matter.